# Functoriality of fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to prove the following statement:
If $\mathcal{C}_1$ is the category of path connected topological spaces and $\mathcal{C}_2$ is the category of groups, then the mapping $\mathcal{C}_1 \ni X \mapsto \pi_1(X)\in \mathcal{C}_2$ is not a functor. ($\pi_1(X)$ is the fundamental group of $X$).

Idea: I want to see that there is no way of associating to a morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ in $\mathcal{C}_1$ a morphism $f_{*}: \pi_1(X)\rightarrow \pi_1(Y)$ in $\mathcal{C}_2 : \forall f,g \in Mor(\mathcal{C}_1)$ that can be composed, having the equation: $$(g \circ f)_{*}= g_{*} \circ f_{*}$$

But I don't see how can I check that. I'd appreciate your help

Comment: what is $\pi_1(X)$ if you did not specify a base-point?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Our spaces are path connected so $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(X,p), \forall p \in X$. I know that if we are working in $Top_{*}$ (topological spaces with a fixed point) then $\pi_1$ is a functor, but in our case we're in a $Top$ (topological spaces) and I want to see $\pi_1(X)$ is not a functor.

Comment: @miku $\pi_1(X,p) \cong \pi_1(X,q)$ but they are not equal, and yet you need to map a space to a single group called "$\pi_1(X)$". So you have to make some choice.

Comment: As @NajibIdrissi has pointed out, this question is ill-posed. Until the phrasing "...mapping $\mathcal{C}_1\ni X\mapsto\pi_1(X)\in\mathcal{C}_2$" is corrected, this question cannot be answered. There is no such object as $\pi_1(X)$ in the category of groups, there is only a collection of objects $\{\pi_1(X,x)\mid x\in X\}$ in which every object is isomorphic.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by all the objections to the question. I'd have stated the question a bit differently, but it seems perfectly clear and meaningful. Yes, "the" fundamental group of a path-connected space is only well-defined up to non-canonical isomorphism, but since this question only depends on the fundamental group up to isomorphism, that doesn't really matter. It's a nice question.

Comment: @JeremyRickard given that the specific categories being considered are important for this question (as $\pi_1$ is a functor in the right setting), I think it's important that the question be as clear as possible. The probable change would be to say "Pick a single representative object for every isomorphism class of groups and map $X\mapsto \pi_1(X)$ where $\pi_1(X)$ is the chosen representative of $[\pi_1(X,x)]_{\cong}$ for some $x\in X$." We can then talk about whether such a choice of representative is possible so that the mapping of objects can be made into a functor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}$I will show that such a functor cannot "look like" $\pi_1$. Let $S^1$ be the unit circle, let $C$ be the cylinder $S^1 \times [0,1]$ and let $K$ be the Klein bottle, the result of gluing the ends of $C$ together with the reverse orientation. We have $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \pi_1(C) \cong \ZZ$ and $\pi_1(K) \cong \ZZ \ltimes \ZZ$ where the action is by $-1$. We have the following maps:

- $\nu: S^1 \to S^1$, the map that reverses orientation.
- $i_1$ and $i_2: S^1 \to C$, the inclusions of the ends of $C$.
- $g: C \to K$, the map that glues the ends of the cylinder together.

Suppose $G$ were a functor from path connected spaces to abelian groups. If $G$ "looked like $\pi_1$", then we would expect

- $G(\nu) : \ZZ \to \ZZ$ should be $-1$.
- $G(i_1)$ and $G(i_2)$ should induce the same bijection $\ZZ \to \ZZ$.
- $G(g)$ should be an inclusion.

This is impossible. Notice that $g \circ i_1 = g \circ i_2 \circ \nu$, so the first two conditions imply that the generator of $G(g)$ sends the generator of $G(S^1)$ to a $2$-torsion element. But the only $2$-torsion element in $G(K)$ is the identity, contradicting the third condition.

I can prove that the first two conditions must hold. (More generally, I can prove that the functors $G^{\mathrm{ab}}(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ and $H_1(X, \mathbb{Q})$ are naturally isomorphic.)  But I am stumped trying to rule out the possibility that $G(g)$ is the trivial map. I don't want to work on this problem further, so I'm putting this up as a partial answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that $G$ is supposed to land in abelian groups. I think it is reasonable to rule out $G (g) = 0$ axiomatically: after all, for any choice of basepoint $c$ in $C$, $\pi_1 (g) : \pi_1 (C, c) \to \pi_1 (K, c)$ is non-zero.

Comment: I don't think $G$ is supposed to land in abelian groups; $G^{ab}(X)$ is the abelianization of $G(X)$ (the thing which should be naturally isomorphic to $H_1$.)

Comment: Of course it is reasonable to rule it out axiomatically. In high level language, this answer shows that there is no functor (path connected spaces) --> (groups) so that the compositions (path connected pointed spaces) --> (path connected spaces) --> (groups) is $\pi_1$, and that is certainly a more reasonable thing to ask about.

Comment: But the original poster just asked whether there is a functor G: (path connected spaces) --> (groups) for which $G(X) \cong \pi_1(X)$, and gave no compatibility conditions on these isomorphisms. I still can't prove there isn't; can you?

Comment: I just looked back at this old answer of mine, and it isn't true that $G(K)$ has no non-trivial $2$-torsion. It IS true that none of that $2$-torsion is in the part of $G(K)$ that I expect $G(i_1)$ and $G(i_2)$ to land in. I don't have time right now to write a fixed version.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not in the morphisms … it is in the very definition of $\pi_1$ on objects: *which* group do you choose? There are, in principle, infinitely many groups $\pi_1(X,x)$ with $x\in X$, all different (because the underlying sets are different) but isomorphic.
The isomorphism $\pi_1(X,x)\cong \pi_1(X,y)$ is not canonical, as it depends on the choice of a path from $x$ to $y$, so you have as many isomorphisms as many homotopy classes of paths.
Therefore, there is no canonical way to pick a group in the group category and call it **the** fundamental group of $X$. So you cannot even define the map between objects.

Comment: Yes, you can define it on the objects: fix a skeleton of $Grp$. The problem will rather be with the morphisms.

Comment: @Berci Could you please explain to me a little more about the problem on the morphisms? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Although this answer mentions an important issue, it doesn't answer the question at all. See Bercy's comment.